# Term store Management: Available for tagging automatically deactives

Tags: office-365, tagging

I can't select all intended use cases for a term set in the term store management.
"Available for Tagging" deactivates automatically after saving and reloading.
If I create a new term set, everything seems to work fine. But after a couple of minutes, it isn't available for tagging anymore.
An suggestions on fixing this?

My term set has the following structure:

My Termset: Category (Tagging, Site Navigation, Faceted Navigation)

...... Level 1: Subcategory  (Site Navigation, Faceted Navigation)

............ Level 2: Subsubcategory (Site Navigation, Faceted Navigation)

.................. Level 3: Subsubsubcategory (Tagging, Site Navigation, Faceted Navigation)

I'd like a user to pick only items from Level 3 (from a site column). In Addition I'd like to use the categories for a hierarchical global navigation.

I use SharePoint O365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I had been invited as external site collection administrator. So I had to set the termsetowner to everyone.